# Similar function to pd.update() with return?

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a funtion similar to `pd.update()` in the pandas module, which have a return?

Right now i have two dicts containing pandas dataframes. I want to replace the columns in the first dataframe with the similar columns of the second dataframe for all values in the dicts.

I was thinking something like this:

```
df_dict_new = {key: df.update(df_dict2[key]) 
                   for (key, df) in df_dict1.items()
                  }
```

but the method doesn't have a return. Is there a function similar to the `pd.update()`?

Or a smarter way to change the columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since DataFrame is mutable I think you can just do

```
for k in df_dict1:
    df_dict1[k].update(df_dict2[k])
```

And df_dict1 should contain your desired result.

Comment: Way simpler. Works like a charm. Thanks